# Removing string inside brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Good day!

I would like some help in removing strings inside the square brackets and including the square brackets.

The string looks like this:

`$string = "Lorem ipsum dolor<br /> [ Context are found on www.example.com ] <br />some text here. Text here. [test] Lorem ipsum dolor.";`

I just would like to remove the brackets and its contents that contain "www.example.com". I would like to retain `"[test]"` in the string and any other brackets have no `"www.example.com"` in them.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the text you are processing generic HTML markup? Will that markup ever contain `SCRIPT` or `STYLE` elements? (or event handlers in start tags?) If so, one needs to be very careful when removing square-bracketed structures. You may get _less_ than you bargained for!

Comment: It has some HTML markups but there are no `SCRIPT` or `STYLE` whatsoever. I used cURL on a certain url and got the contents that I want to have. But I would like to remove the url of the website in the content.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** The OP has dramatically changed the question. This solution was designed to handle the question in its original (more difficult) form (before the "www.example.com" constraint was added.) Although the following solution has been modified to handle this additional constraint, a simpler solution would now probably suffice (i.e. anubhava's answer).

Here is my tested solution:

```php
function strip_bracketed_special($text) {
    $re = '% # Remove bracketed text having "www.example.com" within markup.
          # Skip comments, CDATA, SCRIPT & STYLE elements, and HTML tags.
          (                      # $1: HTML stuff to be left alone.
            <!--.*?-->           # HTML comments (non-SGML compliant).
          | <!\[CDATA\[.*?\]\]>  # CDATA sections
          | <script.*?</script>  # SCRIPT elements.
          | <style.*?</style>    # STYLE elements.
          | <\w+                 # HTML element start tags.
            (?:                  # Group optional attributes.
              \s+                # Attributes separated by whitespace.
              [\w:.-]+           # Attribute name is required
              (?:                # Group for optional attribute value.
                \s*=\s*          # Name and value separated by "="
                (?:              # Group for value alternatives.
                  "[^"]*"        # Either double quoted string,
                | \'[^\']*\'     # or single quoted string,
                | [\w:.-]+       # or un-quoted string (limited chars).
                )                # End group of value alternatives.
              )?                 # Attribute values are optional.
            )*                   # Zero or more start tag attributes.
            \s*/?>               # End of start tag (optional self-close).
          | </\w+>               # HTML element end tags.
          )                      # End #1: HTML Stuff to be left alone.
        | # Or... Bracketed structures containing www.example.com
          \s*\[                  # (optional ws), Opening bracket.
          [^\]]*?                # Match up to required content.
          www\.example\.com      # Required bracketed content.
          [^\]]*                 # Match up to closing bracket.
          \]\s*                  # Closing bracket, (optional ws).
        %six';
    return preg_replace($re, '$1', $text);
}
```

Note that the regex skips removal of bracketed material from within: HTML comments, CDATA sections, SCRIPT and STYLE elements and from within HTML tag attribute values. Given the following XHTML markup (which tests these scenarios), the above function correctly removes only the bracketed contents within html element contents:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test special removal. [Remove this www.example.com]</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .test.before {
            content: "[Do not remove www.example.com]";
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[ ["Do not remove www.example.com"] ]]>
        var ob = {};
        ob["Do not remove www.example.com"] = "stuff";
        var str = "[Do not remove www.example.com]";
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- <![CDATA[ ["Do not remove www.example.com"] ]]> -->
<div title="[Do not remove www.example.com]">
<h1>Test special removal. [Remove this www.example.com]</h1>
<p>Test special removal. [Remove this www.example.com]</p>
<p onclick='var str = "[Do not remove www.example.com]"; return false;'>
    Test special removal. [Do not remove this]
    Test special removal. [Remove this www.example.com]
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the same markup after being run through the PHP function above:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test special removal.</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .test.before {
            content: "[Do not remove www.example.com]";
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[ ["Do not remove www.example.com"] ]]>
        var ob = {};
        ob["Do not remove www.example.com"] = "stuff";
        var str = "[Do not remove www.example.com]";
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- <![CDATA[ ["Do not remove www.example.com"] ]]> -->
<div title="[Do not remove www.example.com]">
<h1>Test special removal.</h1>
<p>Test special removal.</p>
<p onclick='var str = "[Do not remove www.example.com]"; return false;'>
    Test special removal. [Do not remove this]
    Test special removal.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This solution should work quite well for just about any valid (X)HTML you can throw at it. (But please, no funky [shorttags](http://www.w3.org/QA/2007/10/shorttags.html) or [SGML comments](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/SGMLComments.html)!)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor<br /> [ Context are found on www.example.com ] <br />some text here. Text here. [test] Lorem ipsum dolor.";
$str = preg_replace('~\[[^]]*?www\.example\.com[^]]*\]~si', "", $str);
var_dump($str);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
string(83) "Lorem ipsum dolor<br />  <br />some text here. Text here. [test] Lorem ipsum dolor."
```

PS: It will work with line broken in multiple lines.

Comment: No need to use *e* option (evil), but ungreedy option should be useful here

Comment: @soju: No `e` option, it was a copy/paste error. I removed it immediately after posting here.

Comment: @Viswanathan Iyer: This code just strips everything between `[` and `]` including square brackets. There is no `<br/>` to EOL conversion anywhere.

Comment: @anubhava in output it only shows "Lorem ipsum dolor [newlien] some text here"

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift reply. Sorry for this but there are some strings in the brackets that I would like to retain. I just would like to delete brackets and its contents that has www.example.com in it. How will I accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: @Viswanathan Iyer: Please look at the source in browser. Browser is interpreting `<br/>` here.

Comment: @user704278: That is very different than the posted problem. But still can be done. Would you please update your question with an  **EDIT** section with example input/output.

Comment: @i think questioner doesn't want to interpreate <br/>

Comment: @Viswanathan Iyer: Interpretation is all in browser not in the code. Run above code from command line and you will see `<br/>` :) Anyway OP is about to change question with more complex requirement as per comments above.

Comment: @anubhava: I have updated my question and posted my example. Thanks!

Comment: @user704278: I updated my answer to do what you wanted. Pls verify.

Comment: @anubhava: Thank you very much! It worked! Other brackets are not affected. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Would you pls mark this answer as accepted to close this Q&A for benefit of other users.

Comment: @ridgerunner Thanks a lot mate, changed the answer to `'~\[[^]]*?www\.example\.com[^]]*?\]~smi'

Comment: +1 Good answer. (But if you want to get really OCD about avoiding any possible HTML side effect damage, check out my answer!) 8^)

Comment: Oops. You need to escape the `]` inside the char classes. Also you don't need the `'m'` modifier and lazy modifier on the second char class star.

Comment: @ridgerunner: Thanks, Removed `m` and lazy part however my understanding is that inside `[` and `]` there is no need to escape `]`. It has always worked in my code without escaping on all other platforms like sed, perl, php etc. But may be php needs it, I will check this.

Comment: @anubhava: Yes you are correct. I guess it works like the `"-"` where it is ok to be unescaped as long as it is at the start (or end) of the char class. Hey, I just learned something new - Thanks!

Comment: Yes I also believe that it works like hyphen `-`. Square brackets work like magic in regex, I am also learning new things every day on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression something like `/\[.*?\]/`. The backslashes are necessary, otherwise it will try to match any single character `.`, `*`, or `?` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift reply. Sorry for this but there are some strings in the brackets that I would like to retain. I just would like to delete brackets and its contents that has www.example.com in it. How will I accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: @user704278: Try `/\[[^]]*www\.example\.com[^]]*\]/` then. That matches an open-bracket, then any number of non-close-bracket characters, then the string "www.example.com", then any number of non-close-bracket characters, then the close bracket.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method I can think of is using a regular expression to math everything between `[` and `]` then replace it with `""`. The code below will replace the string you used in the example. If the actual strings that need to be removed are more complex you can change the regular expression to match then. I recommend using [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/) for testing your regular expressions.

`$string = preg_replace("\[[A-Za-z .]*\]","",$string);`

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift reply. Sorry for this but there are some strings in the brackets that I would like to retain. I just would like to delete brackets and its contents that has www.example.com in it. How will I accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: I can work with that. Each index of the array $pattern will match a different feature you are looking to remove. `$pattern[0]` matches the left bracket with or without the adjoining space. `$pattern[1]` matches the right bracket with or without the adjoining space. `$pattern[2]` matches the string www.anything.com. The array $replace is made of the strings you want to replace things with.
`$pattern = array("\[(\s)?","(\s)?\]","\swww.[\w]*.com\s");`
`$replace = array("",""," ");`
`$string = preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$string);`

Answer (score 0):

The below code will change `<br/>` to newline characters:

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor<br />[ Context are found on www.example.com ] <br />some text here";
$str = preg_replace( "/\[[^\]]*\]/m", "", $str);
echo $str;
```

Output:

> Lorem ipsum dolor
>
> some text here